# Fixing "has the same erasure as..but does not override" for subclass w/ same method signature but new implementation?

Tags: java, json, generics, inheritance, type-erasure

In java I have a class which extends `JsonProvider.java` as `RootlessJsonProvider.java` that allows the class to work with JSON without a root element.

I'm attempting to override the method `readFrom` which is still defined with the exact same method signature as the class that implements it:

```
    @Override
    public Object readFrom(final Class<Object> type, final Type genericType,
            final Annotation[] anns, final MediaType mtype,
            final MultivaluedMap<String, String> headers,
            final InputStream inputStream) {

        InputStream inputStreamNew = null;

        if (type != null) {
            final XmlRootElement rootElement = type
                    .getAnnotation(XmlRootElement.class);
            if (rootElement != null) {
                inputStreamNew = transformStreamForDropRootElement(rootElement,
                        inputStream);
            }
        }

        return super.readFrom(type, genericType, anns, mtype,
                headers, inputStreamNew);
    }
```

But all that's changed is the implementation, to allow rootless json usage.

The error that comes with it is:

```
The method readFrom(Class<Object>, Type, Annotation[], MediaType, MultivaluedMap<String,String>, InputStream) of type RootlessJsonProvider has the same erasure as readFrom(Class, Type, Annotation[], MediaType, MultivaluedMap, InputStream) of type MessageBodyReader but does not override it
```

Changing the method name also doesn't work because it's usage is off the implementation.

i.e.

```
JsonProvider rootlessProvier = new RootlessJsonProvder();

rootlessProvider.rootlessReadFrom(....); //ERROR <---- this method doesn't exist as it's not defined in JsonProvider.java
```

There aren't any parameters based on how this method is used that's less generic of a type, so how can I resolve this error?

Edit:

```
JsonProvider.java
```

part of cxf-jaxrs version 3.1.5

Comment: Looking at [`JsonProvider`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/spi/JsonProvider.html), I don't see any `readFrom(...)` method to override.  What library are you using?

Comment: CXF-JAXRS: package org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider. Version 3.1.5

Comment: Any reason you didn't keep the generic type parameter for the class? I believe if you don't need it then the first parameter becomes `Class type` not `Class<Object> type` to fix the erasure issue. If you do need it then adding it correctly will also fix the issue and is the preferred way of fixing it.

Comment: Do you  `extend JsonProvider<Object>`?

Comment: @GeorgeMulligan the way it's used is for that param, it'll give a class, so readFrom(SomeClassOfOurs.class......)

Comment: @AJNeufeld No it's just extends JSONProvider {

Comment: Your `RootlessJsonProvider` should be generic as well and pass its type to the `JSONProvider`. `public class RootlessJsonProvider<T> extends JSONProvider<T>`. That way the method can keep the type signature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function signature is

```
class JsonProvider<T> {
    T readFrom(Class<T> ...) {
    }
}
```

You need to extend the class properly.

```
class RootlessJsonProvider extends JsonProvider<SomeClassOfOurs> {
    @Override
    SomeClassOfOurs readFrom(Class<SomeClassOfOurs> ...) {
    }
}

JsonProvider<SomeClassOfOurs> rootlessProvider = new RootlessJsonProvider(...);
```

Or,

```
class RootlessJsonProvider<T> extends JsonProvider<T> {
    @Override
    T readFrom(Class<T> ...) {
    }
}

JsonProvider<SomeClassOfOurs> rootlessProvider = new RootlessJsonProvider<>(...);
```